# How can I remove the white space when I turn the Mathematica notebook (.nb) into PDF (.pdf)?

Tags: pdf-format

The Mathematica notebook:

[image: The Mathematica notebook]

The PDF file:

[image: the PDF file]

I don't know if there is something wrong with my notebook setting ratio or something.